# Has the Force ever refused a Force sensitive's request?

Tags: star-wars

For instance, Count Dooku wants to Force Lightning the hell out of Padme but it's the Will of the Force that Luke and Leia have to be born, so Dooku can't inflict lethal damage upon her, no matter how much he wants to, has something like that ever happened in Canon or Legends?

Comment: Yes, Dooku casts Force lightning aiming to kill baby Luke, but Padme's sacrifice shields Luke, and the lightning bounces back at Dooku and kills him instead. Luke only got a small scar from that incident. Now I just need to find a reference for that.

Comment: Here's your reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter#Early_years.

Comment: Yeah, it refused Darth Maul's request to slay Obi-Wan Kenobi. Many times.

Comment: Darth Maul must have had split feelings about slaying Obi-Wan.

Comment: Do you count Luke failing to lift the X-wing as a refusal?

Comment: That's lacking the skill or the mindset needed for the task, it was more of a certainly possible feat, say, Force Lightning C3-PO to a crisp, but since C3-PO is essential to the Galaxy in the form of helping Luke, the Force outright makes it impossible to do so.

Answer (score 2):

In Legends canon, definitely yes.

1. Pretty much any Sith Lord who died, especially Darth Plagueis. Clearly, they didn't want to die, and tried to use the Force to survive.
2. The way Mi&^*&^*s manipulated the Force and instead of whatever Plagueis planned, created Whiny Anakin Skywalker, The Chosen One.

Comment: Is the death of sith lords really a refusal by the force or just not possible / a lack of ability? I would look for evidence that the feat was otherwise possible but unable to be performed at a given time for no other apparent reason.

Comment: @Jack - you can argue it either way. Depends, as Obi-Wan would say, on your point of view. But Sith Lords unquestionably had superior ability to bend the Force to their bidding, and they were all super afraid to die.